# how do I make a sub sub menu with css?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, submenu

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y7pw.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy6hq.jpg

Please see image above, what I want to do is push "gloves" and "boots" tab to the left of "blah UGG"

I tried to set the sub menu to position relative and the sub sub menu to position absolute but then the sub sub menu disappears, how do I push the sub sub menu to the left of the sub menu?

Here are my HTML:

```
<div id="nav-bar" class="cf">
                <nav class="cf">
                    <ul class="topmenu">
                        <li class="hometop"><a href="#"class="hometop">Home</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#" >Catagory</a>
                            <ul class="submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Blah Blah</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Blah UGGdfddfdf</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Boots</li>
                                        <li>Gloves</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li ><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li ><a href="#">How To Order</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.cf ul li{
float:left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style:none;
font-family:"open sans", sans-serif;

}

.cf li a {
display:block;
padding:0 1em;
line-height: 2.5em;
color:#FFFFFF;
}

.cf li a:hover {
background-color:#ffa627;
}


li{
position:relative;
}
ul.submenu {
float:none;
background: #222;
position:absolute;
left:-9000em;
z-index:1;
width:200px;
height:auto;
}

.topmenu li:hover ul{
left:0;
}   

ul.submenu li {
float:none;
font-size: 12px;
position:relative;

}

.submenu li ul li {
float:none; 
color:#FFFFFF;
display:block;
padding:0 1em;
line-height: 2.5em;

}

#nav-bar nav {
background-color: #222;

}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
content: " "; /* 1 */
display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: can u add it on jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider changing the `float: left;` to `float: right`:

```
.cf ul li{
float:right;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style:none;
font-family:"open sans", sans-serif;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all those nested tags and clearfixes. Look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/rtnDu).
Whenever you have floated elements, use `overflow: hidden` on their parent. This makes the parent fit its children's content.